# ORA-02292: integrity constraint (XXX.JOB_EXEC_PARAMS_FK) violated - child record found in Spring Batch

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-batch, sql-delete

I was looking to delete the

```
delete from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where JOB_INSTANCE_ID=18380;
```

But I am getting the below error. This is specific to Spring Batch

> ```
> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
> delete from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where JOB_INSTANCE_ID=18380
> Error report -
> ORA-02292: integrity constraint (XXX.JOB_EXEC_PARAMS_FK) violated - child record found
> ```

I also look at the

```
CREATE TABLE "XXX"."BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION" 
   (    "JOB_EXECUTION_ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "VERSION" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "JOB_INSTANCE_ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATE_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "START_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT NULL, 
    "END_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT NULL, 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "EXIT_CODE" VARCHAR2(2500 BYTE), 
    "EXIT_MESSAGE" VARCHAR2(2500 BYTE), 
    "LAST_UPDATED" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION" VARCHAR2(2500 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION" PRIMARY KEY ("JOB_EXECUTION_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "XXX_STD_TBL"  ENABLE, 
     SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (FOREIGN KEY) COLUMNS, 
     SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (UNIQUE INDEX) COLUMNS, 
     SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (PRIMARY KEY) COLUMNS, 
     SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP "GGS_766075" ("JOB_EXECUTION_ID") ALWAYS, 
     CONSTRAINT "JOB_INST_EXEC_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("JOB_INSTANCE_ID")
      REFERENCES "XXX"."BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" ("JOB_INSTANCE_ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "XXX_STD_TBL" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/3.0.x/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html and you will see the linkage to the child records.

Just delete the relevant child records 1st and then you can delete the parent ones..

Comment: I am not clear with the solution. Could you please provide exact query ?

Comment: You cannot delete a parent record without 1st deleting its children. There is no "exact query" . Please look at the schema and delete the child records of the parent record you are trying to delete..